# Hue server error "checkJobBrowserStatus" cloudera hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue

I have some problem with accessing to Hue webUI. I just get

> "500 server error"

to every acces to any web page on the Hue. The sample of the error:

[image: screenshoot of error]

From log file i got some information about type of this error

```
 
[12/Dec/2017 01:00:53 -0800] views        ERROR    JS ERROR: {"msg":"ReferenceError: checkJobBrowserStatus is not defined","url":"http://10.40.2.89:8888/hue/","line":1584,"column":12,"stack":"@http://10.40.2.89:8888/hue/:1584:13\nn.Callbacks/j@http://10.40.2.89:8888/static/desktop/ext/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.e40ec2161fe7.js:2:26852\nn.Callbacks/k.fireWith@http://10.40.2.89:8888/static/desktop/ext/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.e40ec2161fe7.js:2:27661\n.ready@http://10.40.2.89:8888/static/desktop/ext/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.e40ec2161fe7.js:2:29482\nI@http://10.40.2.89:8888/static/desktop/ext/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.e40ec2161fe7.js:2:29656\n"}
```

when i try to open other web pages i get the same error

```
[12/Dec/2017 01:04:56 -0800] views        ERROR    JS ERROR: {"msg":"ReferenceError: checkJobBrowserStatus is not defined","url":"http://10.40.2.89:8888/metastore/tables/","line":1584,"column":12,"stack":"@http://10.40.2.89:8888/metastore/tables/:1584:13\nn.Callbacks/j@http://10.40.2.89:8888/static/desktop/ext/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.e40ec2161fe7.js:2:26852\nn.Callbacks/k.fireWith@http://10.40.2.89:8888/static/desktop/ext/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.e40ec2161fe7.js:2:27661\n.ready@http://10.40.2.89:8888/static/desktop/ext/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.e40ec2161fe7.js:2:29482\nI@http://10.40.2.89:8888/static/desktop/ext/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.e40ec2161fe7.js:2:29656\n"}
```

and so on , similar errors on the any web page.

I've attached the [full log file on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zql_jhNB_F5BiSMj9SDOtFL6AWPDWKSb)

I'm trying to open a web interface HUE with Iceweasel on Debian.

Cloudera version is CDH5 (CDH 5.13.0).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [indexer] app was blacklisted ([desktop] section in /hue/desktop/dump_config), so Hue won't work properly.

Also, looks like you are on the old UI, it is recommended to switch back to 
Hue 4.

```
[12/Dec/2017 01:04:53 -0800] middleware   INFO     Processing exception: u'indexer' is not a registered namespace: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg/django/db/transaction.py", line 371, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/apps/metastore/src/metastore/views.py", line 240, in show_tables
    'source_type': _get_servername(db),
  File "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_util.py", line 230, in render
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_util.py", line 148, in _render_to_response
    return django_mako.render_to_response(template, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_mako.py", line 125, in render_to_response
    return HttpResponse(render_to_string(template_name, data_dictionary), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_mako.py", line 114, in render_to_string_normal
    result = template.render(**data_dict)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/mako/template.py", line 443, in render
    return runtime._render(self, self.callable_, args, data)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 786, in _render
    **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 818, in _render_context
    _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 844, in _exec_template
    callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmpMMurVL/metastore/metastore.mako.py", line 142, in render_body
    __M_writer(escape(unicode( assist.assistPanel() )))
  File "/tmp/tmpMMurVL/metastore/assist.mako.py", line 497, in render_assistPanel
    __M_writer(escape(unicode( url('indexer:importer_prefill', source_type='all', target_type='table') )))
  File "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_mako.py", line 131, in url
    return reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=view_args)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 532, in reverse
    key)
NoReverseMatch: u'indexer' is not a registered namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late, but thought of posting the solution to help others.

I was able to get this page working by setting "share_jobs" to "true" in "/etc/hue/conf.empty/hue.ini"

So the following worked for me:

```
[jobbrowser]
    # Share submitted jobs information with all users. If set to false,
    # submitted jobs are visible only to the owner and administrators.
    share_jobs=true
```